# php : rewritten url not default url

Tags: php

I am using xampp on ubuntu 17 and there is this app am developing and i am trying to implement url rewrite. I have allowed url rewritingin httpd.conf and i have set up my .htaccess as below :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Dashboard$ home.php
```

The home.php page is to load afterthe user has successfully logged in but the problem i am having is anytime i log in, i see http://127.0.0.1/home.php in my address bar instead of http://127.0.0.1/Dashboard as in my .htaccess file.

However if i manually enter http://127.0.0.1/Dashboard in my address bar i am taken to the home page with the right url (http://127.0.0.1/Dashboard) displayed.

Comment: How did you manage the login. are you redirecting the client after a login ? and what is the action attribute of the login form ?

Comment: I logged in by entering the login credentials and the this is the action attribut on the login form  :                                                                             
       <form method="post" action="assets/inc/process.inc.php" autocomplete="off" >  and this is the relevant part of the process.inc.php file :define("ACTIONS", array(
       'login' => array(
            'object' => 'User',
            'method' => 'Login',
            'header' => 'Location: ../../home.php'
            )
     )
   )    the header part is the location to redirect user after loging in

Comment: OK, then redirect him to the Dashboard as you want